# mocha chai test on node api always receive 404 status

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, restify

I am creating this test file

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let server = require('../index');
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Users', () => {
  describe('/GET users', () => {
    it('it should GET all the users', (done) => {
      chai.request(server).get('/user/get-all-users').end((err, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(200)
          done()
        });
    });
  });
});
```

This route works just fine, but when running on test I always get test failure 404

I am using restify for running my server,

```
global.server = restify.createServer({
    url     : config.base_url,
    name    : config.name,
    version : config.version,
    log     : bunyanWinston.createAdapter(log),
  })
```

Comment: is your server contains right server url?

Comment: My url is localhost:3000

Comment: server variable in your context looks like an object 
show console.log(server)

Comment: If I console.log(server), I  get this https://pastebin.com/3MxpQr1H

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out

this is my server:

```
'use strict'

/**
 * Module Dependencies
 */
const config        = require('./config'),
  restify       = require('restify'),
  bunyan        = require('bunyan'),
  winston       = require('winston'),
  bunyanWinston = require('bunyan-winston-adapter'),
  mongoose      = require('mongoose')

/**
 * Logging
 */
global.log = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: 'info',
      timestamp: () => {
        return new Date().toString()
      },
      json: true
    }),
  ]
})

/**
 * Initialize Server
 */
global.server = restify.createServer({
  url     : config.base_url,
  name    : config.name,
  version : config.version,
  log     : bunyanWinston.createAdapter(log),
})

/**
 * Middleware
 */
server.use(restify.jsonBodyParser({ mapParams: true }))
server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable))
server.use(restify.queryParser({ mapParams: true }))
server.use(restify.fullResponse())


/**
 * Error Handling
 */
server.on('uncaughtException', (req, res, route, err) => {
  log.error(err.stack)
  res.send(err)
});

/**
 * Lift Server, Connect to DB & Bind Routes
 */
server.listen(config.port, 'localhost', function() {

  mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    log.error('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err)
    process.exit(1)
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('open', function(err) {

    if (err) {
      log.error('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err)
      process.exit(1)
    }

    log.info(
      '%s v%s ready to accept connections on port %s in %s environment. %s',
      server.name,
      config.version,
      config.port,
      config.env,
      server.url
    )

    require('./api/routes/')

  })

  global.db = mongoose.connect(config.db.uri)

})

module.exports = server
```

I was requiring the routes files inside the callback listen function. The routes this way works, but the chai can not find the routes. Just removing the routes from the callback and putting it on my index.js, it works just fine.

Comment: Life saver. Thank you :)

Comment: May coding gods bless you